# Remove pair duplicates from a std::set C++

Tags: c++, stl

Hello I have a std::set of pair that contains the following elements:

```
set<pair<string, int> > mapElem;

apples 1
apples 2
at 1
eating 1
eating 2
football 1
going 1
today 1
today 2
today 3
today 4
today 5
tommy 1
tommy 2
```

I need to find a way to remove the duplicates and to remain only the ones with the highest second pair. (Sorry if this or the title is confusing)
edit: if possible without using std::map !

```
apples 2
at 1
eating 2
football 1
going 1
today 5
tommy 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
map<string, int> aMap(mapElem.begin(), mapElem.end());
set<pair<string, int> > Temp(aMap.begin(), aMap.end());
mapElem.swap(Temp);
```

Without map:

```
set<pair<string, int> >::iterator nextit = mapElem.begin();
while (nextit != mapElem.end()) {
  set<pair<string, int> >::iterator it = nextit++;
  if (nextit != mapElem.end()) {
    if (it->first == nextit->first) {
      mapElem.erase(it);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Added an alternative without map

Answer (score 2):

Note that the contents of the set are sorted, first by the string, then by the integer. So to remove all but the highest-valued entry for each string value, find the range with that string value and remove all but the last one. Something like this (untested):

```
for (iterator i = map.begin(); i != map.end(); ) {
    for (iterator j = i; j != map.end(); ) {
        iterator k = j++;
        if (j == map.end() || j->first != i->first) {
            map.erase(i,k);
            i = j;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `std::set` seems a rather odd container for your original data.

Anyway, just iterate over the set, and use a `std::map` to store the pairs with highest value. For each pair, if the pair in the map has lower value, update it.

An ordinary for-loop will do nicely, don't think about `for_each` and such (keep it simple).

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: ahh sorry, i forgot to say that i want without using map ( dont ask why) :)

Comment: @vBx: Why can't we ask why? Knowing your restrictions is important to helping solve your problem!

Comment: @ Jefromi: because im doing a project and the project explicity says dont use map, any containers but map no, that way i say dont ask, becaus eits a ridiculos think not to use map, so i need to complicat myself with thsi code